# Bootstrap can change the color of navbar but can't get rid of the color?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
/*This is for the overall look of the page, what font and the repeated background image*/
body {

    background-image: url("../Assets/crossword.png");
    font-family: Rockwell, "Courier New", Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;

}

/*This is just to get the main content of the page centered*/
#mainBody {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}


.navbar-custom {
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- This is the title of the first page -->
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- This is the viewport settings for bootstrap -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- These are the javascript, CSS, and jquery file scripts -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/MyStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainBody">
       
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom">

        </nav>
            

            
       
     </div>
     
  
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why I am having so much trouble with this nav bar. Trying bootstrap because its supposed to make things easier..

But I can change the color of navbar background to say blue. But if I give the background color none. it does nothing.

I have tried marking it important, I seen suggestions to make it navbar-default and can't get it to work. I just want to background to be transparent and not have anything in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`none` is not a color, so you can't use it as the background color. You can use `transparent` instead.

Another problem you have is the `navbar-inverse` class in your `<nav>` element, and it will get higher precedence.

You can use `.navbar-custom.navbar-inverse` to fix this:

```css
/*This is for the overall look of the page, what font and the repeated background image*/
body {

    background-image: url("../Assets/crossword.png");
    font-family: Rockwell, "Courier New", Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;

}

/*This is just to get the main content of the page centered*/
#mainBody {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}


.navbar-custom.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="mainBody">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom">

  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Dear lord god, that's all it was, it's beer and Witcher 3 time haha

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For transparent background you need:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```